# Android ViewPager: Issue with random calls of onPageSelected in a loop

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have app which has `TabLayout` implemented with `ViewPager`. I'm not using Fragments but custom Pages in ViewPagerAdapter.

Issue what I experience is right as app starts, if user is tapping on all tabs at the same time extremely fast during first 2-3 seconds of app start, `ViewPagerAdapter` bugs out and it is constantly calling `onPageChange` on index 0 and then 2 in a loop. So my screens start to automatically bounce from first to 3rd tab and user cant stop it.

Anyone experienced this bug? I cant even find out why it is happening. It seems like its some internal bug inside `ViewPagerAdapter` component at this point. Because I even disable `TabLayout` tabs `onInterceptTouchEvent` between tab clicks.

As I mentioned in a comment below, I have issue with `instantiateItem()` function inside my `PagerAdapter`. This function is sometimes not called, therefore my layout for `Page` is not initialized. Any suggestion how to force it to be called every time I switch screen to have all `View` related variables initialized properly?

```
protected fun createCustomTabScreenFlow(){
        mainPagerAdapter = FlowViewPagerAdapter(mainFlowList)
        mainViewPager.adapter = mainPagerAdapter
        mainViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = mainFlowList.size

        mainViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                backButtonStatus(isEnabled = true)
                App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: -------")
                val page  = mainFlowList[position]
                App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: onPageSelected: new: ${page::class.java} current: ${mainCurrentPage?.let { it::class.java }?:"null"}")
                App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: setTabsEnabled: onPageSelected")
                setTabsEnabled(false)
                if (hasVisibleTabs){
                    if (page != mainCurrentPage){
                        //switch automatically
                        App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: onPageSelected: switch to page: ${page::class.java}")
                        mainCurrentPage?.onScreenRemoved()
                        mainCurrentPage?.setScreenVisibleState(false)
                        switchScreen(page::class.java)
                    } else {
                        App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: onPageSelected: switch to page: same page")
                        App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: setTabsEnabled: onPageSelected - error")
                        setTabsEnabled(tabsInitialized)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        mainTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mainViewPager)
        (0..mainTabLayout.tabCount).forEach { tab->
            mainFlowList.getOrNull(tab)?.icon?.let {
                mainTabLayout.getTabAt(tab)?.let { tabItem->
                    val tabItemView = CustomResources.inflateLayout(layoutInflater, R.layout.custom_tab_item, null, false) as ViewGroup
                    tabItemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon).setImageResource(it)
                    tabItem.customView = tabItemView
                    tabItem.customView?.requestLayout()
                }
            }
        }

        onPagerIntialized()
    }

    private var tabsInitialized = false
    open fun onPagerIntialized(){
        App.log("AppNavigationFlow: MainTabActivity: setTabsEnabled: onPagerInitialized")
        tabsInitialized = true
        setTabsEnabled(true)
    }


private var isInSwitchingProcess = false
fun switchScreen(
    screen: Class<out FlowScreen>,
    payload: List<ScreenPayload>? = null,
    action: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    useAnim: Boolean = true,
){
    try {
        val index = mainFlowList.indexOfFirst { item -> item::class.java == screen }
        if (index >= 0){
            delayedScreenSelection {
                if (!isInSwitchingProcess && tabsInitialized){
                    isInSwitchingProcess = true
                    mainTabLayout.getTabAt(index)?.select()
                    mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(index, useAnim)
                    mainPagerAdapter.getPageAtPos(index)?.apply {
                        mainCurrentPage = this
                        mainCurrentPage?.apply {
                            setScreenVisibleState(true)
                            clearPayload()
                            clearAction()
                        }
                        payload?.let { mainCurrentPage?.sendPayload(payload) }
                        action?.let { mainCurrentPage?.setAction(action) }
                        onScreenSwitched()
                        isInSwitchingProcess = false
                    }?:kotlin.run {
                        isInSwitchingProcess = false
                        setTabsEnabled(tabsInitialized)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            setTabsEnabled(tabsInitialized)
        }
    }catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException){
        setTabsEnabled(tabsInitialized)
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
class FlowViewPagerAdapter(private var pageList: List<FlowScreen>): PagerAdapter() {

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view == `object`
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return pageList.size
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): View {
        val page = pageList[position]
        val layout = page.getScreen(container)
        container.addView(layout)
        return layout
    }

    var mCurrentView: View? = null
    override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        mCurrentView = `object` as View
        val pager = container as? CustomizableViewPager
        mCurrentView?.let { v->
            pager?.measureCurrentView(v)
        }
    }

    fun getPageAtPos(pos: Int): FlowScreen?{
        return pageList.getOrNull(pos)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return getPageAtPos(position)?.name
    }
}
```

There is possibility that `delayedScreenSelection` caused those weird behaviors with page swapping.

Issue is that this delayed selection also caused something I took for granted and its a speed of animation while tapping on Tabs in `TabLayout` (Animation of `Tab indicator`). Now Tab Indicator is not moving slowly but instantly going to second Tab.

This `post.delayed` caused animation of `TabLayout` to slow down so it looked better.

Is there any correct way how to slow tab indicator down?

I've tried to add custom Scroller inside my ViewPager like this:

```
init {
        try {
            val mScroller = ViewPager::class.java.getDeclaredField("mScroller")
            mScroller.isAccessible = true
            val scroller = FixedSpeedScroller(this.context)
            mScroller.set(this, scroller)
        } catch (_: NoSuchFieldException) {
        } catch (_: IllegalArgumentException) {
        } catch (_: IllegalAccessException) {
        }
    }
```

This slowed down swiping velocity between pages, but it did not slow down actual Tab indicator move velocity.

I don't want to change Page swiping speed (that is correct) but Tab indicator is way too fast relative to page swipe.

Also removing delay function caused that there is no animation between first and second page at all. It does not look smooth

Comment: what's `delayedScreenSelection`?

Comment: 400ms post.delayed function, because I got issues with instantiateItem function for my Page. I got "lateinit property x has not been initialized". Somehow page content was called sooner than instantiateItem got its layout initialized - although it happened on few devices only

Comment: Maybe you can help me with that. Function onScreenSwitched() in that code is responsible for loading any content into Page views. So calling it somewhere else could potentially solve this lateinit issue Ive got.

Comment: The only suggestion I can give you is to get rid of that workaround before trying to fix the other issue. It is one of the things that can cause the weird behaviour you are seeing. I think it isn't a bug in `ViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: Yeah. But first of all I need to find a way (if there is one) how to be sure that ViewPagerAdapter has initialized my Page views. Any sort of callback from ViewPagerAdapter itself but I cant find anything about it in documentation. There is instatiateItem function but it is just return function which is not telling me if actual View was initialized properly. Will post my ViewPagerAdapter.

Comment: For some screens, instantiateItem function is not even called. Which is weird. This function is calling getScreen function which is basically working as onViewCreated/onCreateView Fragment function. But without onViewCreated/onCreateView I cant init anything on that screen.